# cannot convert Entities to Object Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using a context base but I am now using ef 6 this was a way I did it in ef 5 and it worked with object context and not t4 my base case is as follows. I am using linq .

```
public abstract class ContextBase
    {
        public abstract bool SaveChanges();

        protected bool SaveChanges(ObjectContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                int i = context.SaveChanges();

                if (i == 0)
                    return false;

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new EntityContextException("SaveChanges failed.", ex);
            }
        }

        public abstract void DeleteObject(object entity);

        protected void DeleteObject(ObjectContext context, object entity)
        {
            try
            {
                context.DeleteObject(entity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new EntityContextException("DeleteObject failed.", ex);
            }
        }




    }
```

Then in my Context Class I am deriving it here

```
public class SourceContext : ContextBase
{
    public  SMBASchedulerEntities _sourceEntities = new SMBASchedulerEntities();

    public override bool SaveChanges()
    {

        return base.SaveChanges(_sourceEntities);
    }

    public override void DeleteObject(object entity)
    {
        base.DeleteObject(_sourceEntities, entity);
    }
```

}

But when I try to compile it I get the following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.SMBASchedulerEntities' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext'   SMBAScheduler   C:\Projects\Backup
>   of Paitent Source
>   Code\WindowsFormsApplication1\SourceContext.cs    82  Active

Comment: Are you trying to read in EF 6 files that were written in EF 5.  It may not work because the libraries are different.  You are trying to read/write binary structures and the libraries may be defined differently in EF5 & EF6.

Comment: @jdweng how do I use the save and delete objects then in ef6 and no its a fresh created edmx in version

Comment: `protected bool SaveChanges(ObjectContext context)` should be `protected bool SaveChanges(DbContext context)`. EF6 uses `DbContext` object model as replacement of the previous `ObjectContext` (it's still there and  can be obtained from `DbContext`, but normally is not used).